# Removing a set of original assumptions from the result of Reduce

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, sets

I am having trouble using set operations when applying them to lists which cme from the Reduce function. As an example, here is a list of assumptions and an expression for which I would like to know the conditions (in this example, Simplify or Solve might be alternative approaches, but for my needs I obtain the list of conditions using Reduce). The lists obtained are as expected when I output them, but for some reason the extraneous assumptions are not removed when working on the results directly, as shown below:

```
assumptions = {0 < s < 1, 0 < t < 1, 0 < u < 1, x != 0, y != 0};
expr = a  x + b  y + c == d   x + e  y + f;

(* the result is a list of the original assumptions combined with the \
result I want {a\[Equal](-by-c+f+d x+e y)/x} *)
result = Reduce[expr && And @@ assumptions]

(* the complement does not seem to remove the superfluous assumptions \
I included on purpose (the ones on s, t and u): *)
Complement[List @@ result, assumptions]

(* if I print the list, I obtain something **which appears to be** \
equivalent to {0<s<1,0<t<1,0<u<1,x\[NotEqual]0,a\[Equal](-c+f+d x-b \
y+e y)/x,y\[NotEqual]0} *)
Print["Printing the result list:", List @@ result];
Print["Printing the hard-coded list:", {0 < s < 1, 0 < t < 1, 
   0 < u < 1, x != 0, a == (-c + f + d x - b y + e y)/x, y != 0}];

(* yet if I use the complement with the hard-coded list, it now works \
as expected: *)
Complement[{0 < s < 1, 0 < t < 1, 0 < u < 1, x != 0, 
  a == (-c + f + d x - b y + e y)/x, y != 0}, assumptions]
```

I have tested this issue with Intersection and I get the same surprising behavior. My guess is that the list obtained using "List @@ result" does not contain things in exactly the correct format, but I am at a loss as to what is wrong or missing... [Another answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245199/using-simplify-and-reduce-with-assumptions-when-the-inequality-is-already-one-of) discusses the number of non-linear parameters, which does not seem like a related problem; I tried the solution anyhow, but it does not work in the above scenario.

Comment: Simplify[result,assumptions] will remove all the assumptions, but will also rearrange and reformat the solution, which you may not want. Cases[result,a==_][[1]] will extract only the solution and drop the assumptions. Do either of those give you what you want and are simple enough that you can predict how they will behave when you use them in the future?

Comment: @Bill thanks: unfortunately neither of those work for my case. I must use Reduce to obtain a list of possible constraints, so Simplify will not do. Cases would have been interesting, and thanks for that as I did not know about it. Unfortunately, in some instances Reduce yields a==something, but in others it will just yield a list of constraints which I want to capture. Still, a great comment which might help others! Importantly, I am at a loss as to why the "lists" dont seem to work as "sets" whereas they appear to do so when I hard code them?

Comment: `Equal @@ Solve[expr, a][[1, 1]]`

Comment: Rule 1: when any kind of matching doesn't work... look at the `FullForm`. 
 `FullForm[List@@result]` looks VERY different from `FullForm[assumptions]` and I hope studying that will explain why your `Complement` isn't working as you expect. Now you just have to use that clue to figure out WHY it is VERY different. I should have done that before making my first comment. My mistake. Sorry.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Although I had heard of FullForm, it never popped up in my list of things I needed until now. I am thus using the following: replaceInequality[ineq_] := 
  ineq /. Inequality[a_, Less, b_, Less, c_] :> Less[a, b, c]; and then calling Complement[replaceInequality /@ (List @@ result), 
 replaceInequality /@ assumptions]. Not sure if there is a more elegant way to do this...

Comment: Reduce takes at least 2 arguments, not only one. Then, Reduce uses "Inequality" but your assumptions use "Less", therefore, they are not eliminated.